# How to include when a clause in MySQL is within 'where'

Tags: mysql

I need to implement the below condition in random under the `where` condition.

I'm sharing the sample script below. The way I was implementing it is wrong I think.

```
select * from 
table1 t1,
table2 t2,
table3 t3,
table4 t4,
table5 t5

CASE 'a'
WHEN a THEN

WHERE 
t1.id = t2.id
t1.id = t3.id
t1.id = t5.id
t1.id = t4.id
END
```

or

```
select * from 
table1 t1,
table2 t2,
table3 t3,
table4 t4,
table5 t5

WHERE 
t1.id = t2.id
t1.id = t3.id
t1.id = t5.id
CASE 'a'
WHEN a THEN
t1.id = t4.id
END
```

Please advice me for the same.

Comment: What do you mean you to implement it in random? For me those queries don't make any sense. What are they supposed to get you? What is your actual goal?

Comment: Do you get an error message?